# HTML5 input validation pattern - must include both alpha and numeric characters?

Tags: html, input

I am trying to create a regular expression for HTML5 text input validation which has the following:

- At least one non-white space character
- Must contain a mixture of letters and numbers (upper or lowercase are acceptable)
- Special characters (-, /, etc.) are acceptable

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you want is something like

Check it on [rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/)

Simple pattern for accepting special characters like - . _

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$
```

Pattern for all case Characters with Special Characters & Numeric

```
 (?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d).+$
```

Comment: It looks like this pattern allows alpha or numeric or special characters; however I'm trying to find a pattern which requires both alpha and numeric characters (ie. at least 1 letter and 1 number)

Comment: Looks like this works so far:   (?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d).+$

Comment: Yeah .This is working.